# PHP sprintf considered harmful?

Tags: php, security, printf

A few years ago, I learned about [Format String Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) in C the hard way. Now, I recently saw some PHP code like this:

```
<?php
echo sprintf($_GET['format'], $_GET['value1'], $_GET['value2']);
```

I tried run this like this with `$_GET['format']` set to strings like `%s%s%s...`, but PHP just exists with `PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in file.php on line 2`. Isn't it still possible to do a format string attack?

Comment: Well, the number of %s's in $_GET['format'] need to match the number of arguments, or you have the too few arguments error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in any traditional sense, as PHP's [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) doesn't support any of the really dangerous conversions like `%n`. A user-controlled format string can still cause some limited havoc (consider `%99999999s`), but about the worst I think it could do would be to consume memory and time.

Answer (score 2):

I also found an integer overflow. Which leads to this:

```
<?php
echo sprintf('%2147483646$s', "foo"); # Warning: Too few arguments
echo sprintf('%2147483647$s', "foo"); # Warning: Argument number must be greater than zero
```

I filed this as [PHP Bug #61531](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61531). I am not sure, if it may be exploitable.

Answer (score -1):

Higher-level languages tend to validate the number of arguments passed instead of blindly trusting the programmer. You will need to find another attack vector.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if there is a PHP sprintf() vulnerability, but, example code appears to be a prime example of how not to do things.

As far as I'm concerned, sprintf should help you lock down a string, not the other way around.  For example, this is what I'd consider useful reason to use sprintf():

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "insert into table (myname, myvalue) values ('%s', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['name'] ),
    intval( $_GET['value'] )
);
```

A more useful reason to use sprintf is to borrow its cousin, **vsprintf** and reuse constantly:

```
// takes variable number of parameters
function sanitize() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sql = array_shift( $args );
    foreach( $args as $k => $v ) $args[$k] = mysql_escape_string( $v );
    $safe_sql = vsprintf( $sql, $args );
    return( $safe_sql );
}
```

With it, you can safely isolate parameters from queries and assume they will be sanitized:

```
$t = mysql_query(sanitize(
    "insert into mytable (myname, myvalue) values ('%s', '%s')",
    $_GET['name'],
    $_GET['value']
));
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `sprintf`, and seems to be promoting using something other than PDO to prepare user input for MySQL queries.

Comment: I was making a point that sprintf() shouldn't be used like eval()