# Weird sprintf behavior in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to do `sprintf("<%s>", "Sat");`, but nothing comes out. When you remove the less than symbol, it will start working again. Anyone experience this behavior and whether it expected? as i think it is a bug.

You can even get the same result here with printf.....
http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Except that, you can't test it at the link provided because `Warning: sprintf() has been disabled for security reasons on line 1`

Comment: Anyone know what those security reasons are?

Comment: Try it without `sprintf`.  Try `print '<Sat>';` and see what happens.

Comment: well....reading at SO -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/9895923/31039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser is probably rendering it as a tag. View source to confirm.

http://codepad.org/g5FXZAwa

```
<?php

printf("<%s>", "Sat");
```

Prints `<Sat>`

---

Edit for Yogesh.

```
<?php

echo sprintf("<%s>", "Sat");
```

Prints `<Sat>`

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Why did I miss this... :/

Comment: why so many upvotes? OP is asking the question for `sprintf` and Mike is giving code for `printf`.

Comment: Because he explained what is happening.

Comment: "echo sprintf" is functionally the same as "printf". I've been overworking myself and didn't look at the source.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this happens because `<Sat>` is interpreted by your browser as a tag.